# Right relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

`hello`, sorry for my english. I will try explain my problem.

For example, we have model `Product`.

Each product has some options:

```
product_1 : option_1 = 50, option_2 = 14, option_3 = 23
```

Whats is the right way?

First - create database, like

```
id | title | option_1 | option_2 | option_3
```

Second - create models and tables, like

```
ProductModel hasMany optionModel 
OptionModel belongsToMany ProductModel

tables in databases: Product, Option, Product_Option_Relationships
```

Third - create some collection in function and table `Product_Option_Relationships` like

```
$options = collect([
  ['id' => '1', 'name' =>'option1'],
  ['id' => '2', 'name' =>'option2'],  
]);
```

Table: `id | product_id | option_id`

Or maybe exist normal way, because first - its too big table, when you have 20 options, second - create new model only for information function, i dont now, its normal? Third - too difficult in view show options name.

Thank you, i hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1):

Generally use the one-to-many, many-to-many relationships 
And the benefit for that you can freely edit any record without modifying the whole column to apply that on your tables :
First we have `products` table which is going to require options foreach 
so we should have the table `options` which is going to combine the options in general then we add a new table `assignOptionsToProducts` which is include keys for both `options` & `products` in this case you're going to have many-to-many or one-to-many relationship as you like

```
Products Table 
id | Name 
1  | Product A
2  | Product B

Options Table
id | Name 
1  | Option A
2  | Option B 

AssignOptionsToProducts Table 
id | Product_id | Option_id
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 1          | 2
3  | 2          | 2
```

As you can see we assigned the same option many times 
And when we want to modify any option you can without modifying each record in other tables and of course you can use each table many times easily

Answer (score 0):

Use the second way. You won't have repeated options. For example:

products

```
id | name
---|------
1  | Car
2  | Bike
```

options

```
id   |  name
-----|------------
1    |  Transport
```

option_product

```
option_id   |  product_id
------------|-------------
1           |  1
1           |  2
```

Using the other ways, you would have the option Transport twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many-to-many relationship and can structure it like so:

Product Model

```
class Product extends Model {
    ...

    public function options() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_options', 'product_id', 'option_id');
    }
}
```

Options Model

```
class Option extends Model {
    ...

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Option', 'product_options', 'option_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

You will need three tables for this to work:

```
Table products

id | name
-----------------
 1 | iBeacon
 2 | Intel Edison

Table options

id | name  
----------
 1 | Price 
 2 | Size

Table product_options 

id | option_id | product_id
---------------------------
 1 |     1     |     2
 2 |     2     |     2
```

You can choose if you want to store a record with the option value in the options table or in the pivot table. I'd place them in the pivot table to keep the options table smaller.

Now you'll be able to assign options to your products like so:

```
...
// Assing options to a product
$product->options()->sync([$optionID, $optionID]);

// Get product's options
$product->options;

// Get products having certain option
$option->products;
...
```